# If Mirage Mirror becomes a copy of a creature, and then is put into the library some how, does it still stay a creature until end of turn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I turn [Mirage Mirror](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMirage%20Mirror%5d) into a copy of a creature, and then put it back in the library, is it still a creature until end of turn, or does it go back to being an artifact in the library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's just an ordinary Mirage Mirror artifact once it's in your library. It won't still be a copy of anything.

The key rule here is:

> [400.7.](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Zone) An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence. There are nine exceptions to this rule:
>
> *(None of the exceptions apply. They're mostly about cards keeping track of each other between zones when they need to.)*

Generally after something moves to a new zone, it's reset to a fresh state of just being whatever the card says.